# Redirect URI error with Google social login in dj-rest-auth

Tags: django, dj-rest-auth

I try to add a google login button to my website, that runs django as the server.
For social authentication I want use [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and tried to go according to it's guides to authenticate with google auth-code flow.

On the client side I use the @react-oauth/google package.
The setup on my django server is this:

```
views.py
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
  adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
  callback_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/"
  client_class = OAuth2Client

urls.py
path("auth/google/", GoogleLogin.as_view(), name="google_login"),
```

The google credentials screen settings:

[image: js origins]
[image: redirect URIs]

Whenever I try to login with google I get an 400 error from the dj-rest-auth view, and when I debugged the code I looked at the response from google(https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token):
I get the following error in the response text(also 400)

{
"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}

It looks like my server send the correct redirect uri in the payload
[image]

Any help or tips with this issue and social auth in general would be very appreciated, thank you.